# I am connecting postgres database with wrong password still i am able to connect the database?

Tags: postgresql

I am connecting postgres database with wrong password and connection string and user role is correct and still i am able to connect the database?

How its possible?

Comment: At least provide us the script you have, and what you are trying to do. Also posting the exact errors could help others in helping you.

Comment: you have trust in hba_file for this connection?..

Answer (score 0):

when you are connecting with database there is a situation when postgres does not ask for password 
1. when you are installing the postgres and creating localhost server first time and making connection without password than it needs only the correct following :- 
  1. username or userrole 
  2. correct connection string

for please visit: http://jtechies.in/orm-tools/hibernate/index.php

Comment: How does that link support your answer?